# My code is supposed to get the value from ComboBox and add a <p> element

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

This code is supposed to get the value from a combobox, create a new paragraph in the website and put the combobox value in that paragraph. I can't seem to find a viable solution on the internet. This is the code:

````
var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("output");

comboBox.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);

function eventHandler(){
    var result = comboBox.options[comboBox.selectedIndex].value;
    addLabel(result);
}

function addLabel(result){
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(result);
    newParagraph.appendChild(newContent);
    document.body.myDiv.appendChild(newParagraph);    
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no myDiv property under `document.body`. Use myDiv variable you assigned in your script.

```js
function addLabel(result){
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(result);
    newParagraph.appendChild(newContent);
    myDiv.appendChild(newParagraph);    
}
```